# Show list of strings in Source List (NSOutlineView) in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to show a simple list of strings in a source list sidebar - similar to that in Finder or the Github app. From reading the [protocol reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSOutlineViewDataSource_Protocol/) I can't see which method is setting what the view displays. So far I have:

```
var items: [String] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item is an item", "Thing"]
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {
    return items[index]
}

func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return false
}
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {
    if item == nil {
        return items.count
    }
    return 0
}
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
    return "ITEM"
}
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, setObjectValue object: AnyObject?, forTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) {
    println(object, tableColumn, item)
}
// Delegate
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, dataCellForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, tem item: AnyObject) -> NSCell? {
    println("Called")
    let view = NSCell()
    view.stringValue = item as String
    return view
}
```

And all I get is a source list with four blank items (No text). Do I need to override another method from the NSOutlineViewDelegate to show the information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're happy to use a *view-based* outline view, rather than a *cell-based* one, you can replace the delegate method `outlineView:dataCellForTableColumn:item`, with its *view* equivalent `outlineView:viewForTableColumn:item:`

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView,
    viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?,
    item: AnyObject) -> NSView? {

    var v = outlineView.makeViewWithIdentifier("DataCell", owner: self) as NSTableCellView
    if let tf = v.textField {
        tf.stringValue = item as String
    }
    return v
}
```

Note that the important call within this method is the `NSTableView` method `makeViewWithIdentifier:owner:`. The first argument to this method - the string *DataCell* - is the value of the `identifier` *Interface Builder* gives to the `NSTableViewCell` object that it automatically inserts into your `NSOutlineView`  when you drag it onto the canvas. This object has a `textField` property, and an `imageView`; all you need to do is set the `stringValue` property of the `textField` to the value of `item`.