# NSOutlineViewDataSource and Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, nsoutlineview

I'm trying to implement a NSOutlineViewDataSource with Swift and when using Swift strings the app is simply crashing. When I change the array `people` to be of NSString it works fine.

According to [Working with Cocoa Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-XID_42) the string bridging should be automatic when you import Foundation.

Here's the data source code:

```
import Cocoa
import Foundation

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSOutlineViewDataSource {

    let people: [String] = ["Mary", "John", "Paul"] // when using NSString it works fine

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, numberOfChildrenOfItem item: AnyObject?) -> Int {
        return item == nil ? people.count : 0
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, isItemExpandable item: AnyObject) -> Bool {
        return false
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, child index: Int, ofItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject {
        return people[index]
    }

    func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        return item
    }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Xcode Version 6.1 (6A1052d)

Xcode project is hosted here: https://github.com/tanob/ExampleNSOutlineView

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour. Using solely the code you provide, when I use either ``String`` or ``NSString`` I don't get a crash, just three empty rows. Are you implementing any delegate methods, or using bindings to get the values showing up in cells?

Comment: I've pushed the project to Github so it might be easier to reproduce. I'm using storyboards and simply connected the `NSOutlineView` datasource outlet to the `ViewController`. The `ViewController` just implements the `NSOutlineDataSourceProtocol`. I'm also using cell-based `NSOutlineView`.

Comment: Thanks for the demo-app - I've got the behaviour now (I assumed you were using a view-based OV).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134062/show-list-of-strings-in-source-list-nsoutlineview-in-swift this answer works and I haven't had any problems with swift Strings

Comment: Here's the crash report I got when running with Appcode: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tanob/ExampleNSOutlineView/master/crash-when-running-through-appcode.txt

Answer (score 2):

I always a bit reluctant to label behaviour I don't understand as a bug, but this feels like one to me.

If you log the values that are passed in to `outlineView:objectValueForTableColumn:byItem` as the table is populated, after the third call the value of `item` is unexpected (using `NSString` the value is always one of your items):

```
func outlineView(outlineView: NSOutlineView, 
    objectValueForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, 
    byItem item: AnyObject?) -> AnyObject? {
        callCount++
        if callCount > people.count {
            println(item)
            return "junk"
        } else {
            return item
        }
    }

// output ->
// call count: 1; <item> value: Optional(Mary)
// call count: 2; <item> value: Optional(John)
// call count: 3; <item> value: Optional(Paul)
// call count: 4; <item> value: Optional(<__NSBlockVariable__: 0x60000004cb40>)
// call count: 5; <item> value: Optional(<RIPData 0x608000043300>) // surely not good!
// call count: 5; <item> value: Optional(<RIPData 0x608000043390>)
// ...
```

Mostly this implementation crashes also, but occasionally the outline view does actually load up - though of course each of the three cells has the value *junk*.

Also interesting is the fact that there doesn't seem to be any problem using `String` values in a cell-based `NSTableView` - I got your data into one with no problems.

So my short answer to your question *why is this happening?* would be a tentative *because you've found a bug* - but a cell-based `NSOutlineView` bug, rather than a rather than a `String` bug.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I've submitted a bug report to Apple.